# Access through multiple and mixed selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

```
<table id="financial101_tab2" class="dxrpControl_Moderno dxrpWithoutHeader_Moderno" style="border-collapse: separate; opacity: 1; margin-left: 0px;">

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="financial101_tab2_RPC" class="dxrp dxrpcontent" style="padding: 6px 10px 10px; border-width: medium; border-style: …r-color: -moz-use-text-color; background-color: transparent;">
            <input id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2ATI" type="hidden" value="0" name="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2ATI"></input>
            <div id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2" class="dxtcLite_Moderno dxtc-top" style="">
                <ul id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_TC" class="dxtc-strip dxtc-stripContainer" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px; width: 624px;">
                    <li class="dxtc-leftIndent" style="height: 23px;">
                    </li>
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_T0" class="dxtc-tab pcTemplates dxtc-lead" style="display: none; cursor: pointer; height: 32px;" onclick="return aspxTCTClick(event, 'BlockControlfinancial101_tab2', 0)">
                        <a class="dxtc-link">
                            <img id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_T0Img" class="D:\Projects\sitcenter\Xcms.Domain\XcmsView\CustomStyleSource\tabStyle.css dxtc-img dx-vam" style="margin-right:;" alt="" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_11-SUXk8"></img>
                            <b class="dxtc-text dx-vam">

                                Гистограмма

                            </b>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0" class="dxtc-activeTab pcTemplates dxtc-lead" style="cursor: default; height: 32px;">
                        <a class="dxtc-link">
                            <img id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0Img" class="D:\Projects\sitcenter\Xcms.Domain\XcmsView\CustomStyleSource\tabStyle.css dxtc-img dx-vam" style="margin-right:;" alt="" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_11-SUXk8"></img>
                            <b class="dxtc-text dx-vam">

                                Гистограмма

                            </b>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_T0S" class="dxtc-spacer" style="width: 3px; height: 23px;"></li>
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_T1" class="dxtc-tab pcTemplates" style="cursor: pointer; height: 32px;" onclick="return aspxTCTClick(event, 'BlockControlfinancial101_tab2', 1)"></li>
                    <li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT1" class="dxtc-activeTab pcTemplates" style="display: none; cursor: default; height: 32px;"></li>
                    <li class="dxtc-rightIndent" style="width: 329px; height: 23px;"></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_CC" class="dxtc-content" style="width: 600px;"></div>
            </div>
            <b class="dx-clear"></b>
            <script id="dxss_1435400798" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to `access <b class="dxtc-text dx-vam"></b>` but I get nothing, or something like ГистограммаГистограммаГистограммаГистограмма multiple times, I need only 1 text, but it iterates over all tables, I have them 5 or 6, I need to get only text of this table, I used this script

```
alert($('#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_TC#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0, a.dxtc-link, b.dxtc-text').text());
```

but it doesn't correctly give result, I need text 'Гистограмма' only once, and only in this table, any ideas?

Comment: Try using `alert($("#financial101_tab2").find(".dxtc-text dx-vam").text());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from Tomer didn't work for me. I think what you are looking for is this:

```
alert($("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0").find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").text());
```

You can simplify the selector to use the closest ID (which should be unique on the page) and select the element with classes `.dxtc-text` and `.dx-vam` using `find()` like this:

```
.find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam")
```

Comment: ok, thats great, and please can you tell me how i can add style to parent.parent of this element? i mean something like this `if ($("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0").find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").text() == 'Гистограмма') {$("#BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_AT0").find(".dxtc-text.dx-vam").parent().parent().css('background', '#000');}` but it doesnt work properly, i need this `<li id="BlockControlfinancial101_tab2_T0" class="dxtc-tab pcTemplates dxtc-lead" style="display: none; cursor: pointer; height: 32px;" onclick="return aspxTCTClick(event, 'BlockControlfinancial101_tab2', 0)">` backgroud